# Generating URL safe encrypted ids in Codeigniter

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, codeigniter-3

For encryption of parameters in url, I am using codeigniter encrypt class after extending it. The purpose of extending was to remove /+- from encryption. This was working fine. But after upgrading to PHP 7.1 it is showing deprecation error of mcrypt related methods and documentation is also recommending to use openssl provided in Encryption library. So I implemented it

```
    $this->load->library('encryption');
    $this->encryption->initialize(
        array('driver' => 'openssl')
    );
    $this->encryption->encrypt($vendor->vid);
```

But its generating encrypted ids with / in it.

8da179e79fee45aa3c569d6c54653c99626d57b074fa599f8a109cb0c5f2edb6d7def3f1a6daf5b449d467976a8a32de0819b9af6d84b068f9ec903d41c2bcb9H/eQluY5LUANEDwmCh+/trIvaJu2Bemj2p9J2MnEMII=

How to generate url safe encrypted parameters using openssl in CI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to this problem is to replace the delimiters that you don't want with another url safe delimiters by extending the core encryption library as you did and use something like this:

```
function encode($string)
{
    $encrypted = parent::encrypt($string);
    if ( !empty($string) )
    {
        $encrypted = strtr($encrypted, array('/' => '~'));
    }
    return $encrypted;
}

function decode($string)
{
    $string = strtr($string, array('~' => '/'));
    return parent::decrypt($string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe not answering your question but can solve in way obfuscating url safe id

for generate encrypt id just like Youtube watch id i use Hashids Spark for CodeIgniter

https://github.com/sekati/codeigniter-hashids

the purpose of this helper is implementing Hashids to generate hashes (like YouTube or Bitly) from numbers to obfuscate database IDs.

installation just like at instruction i modify the hashids_helper.php at line 20

```
require_once FCPATH . 'sparks/sk-hashids/' . HASHIDS_VERSION . '/vendor/Hashids.php';
```

to

```
require_once FCPATH . 'vendor/Hashids.php';  //according to your Hashids path
```